# How do I set a custom image in the facebook sharer dialog?

Tags: facebook, share

How can I load the image in the facebook share dialog?

Using the service sharethis.com

http://screencast.com/t/8UoX80ox

```
<meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="http://medtechhealthdev.com/images/share_big.jpg" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://medtechhealthdev.com/images/share_big.jpg"/>
<link rel="image_src" type="image/jpeg"  href="http://medtechhealthdev.com/images/share_big.jpg" />
```

The problem is that all important meta tags are spelled out. But nazhetii "Share" function does not properly srobatyvaet. Instead, the image prescribed in "meta", it loads the page image. But For an update dialog box, "Share facebook" everything is correct and korektno.

Comment: The image links don't seem to be working. Your question isn't very clear.

Comment: The problem is that all important meta tags are spelled out. But nazhetii "Share" function does not properly srobatyvaet. Instead, the image prescribed in "meta", it loads the page image. But For an update dialog box, "Share facebook" everything is correct and korektno.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check problem with your Facebook Post sharing on Faceboog Debug and the default Image set for sharing as well.

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

So whatever is the issue You can see it there and figure out a solution, Hope this helps.

Here for example: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fmedtechhealthdev.com

In you Image "og:image:secure_url" you are providing "http" and not "https", so that might be creating an issue.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fmedtechhealthdev.com Corrected. Everything remains as before.

Comment: Ya and ur problem is solved, see the thumbnail displayed on Debugger page.

It'll be updated for your website soon as it takes a little time to update the details on Facebook Servers.

And in order to make it sure, Just set the other attributes as well og:url, og: title, og:description, because I can still see the warning there.

Make sure there is no error or warning to make it work properly.

Comment: Set the other OG properties(og:url, og: title, og:description) as well to make sure this works fine for you.